# FirebaseApp.configure method - JSON parsing bug

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed. I get this error after configuring my app delegate with FirebaseApp.configure, causing issues with JSON parsing. Any ideas?

Comment: This is a console warning and has nothing to do with JSON parsing. You should print the parsing error(s) yourself.

Comment: "causing issues"  What are those issues?  Unless you spell them, nobody else but you knows what they are.